# Why did they use LEFT JOIN and choose meta table as outer table in this query ? Isn't it ineffective to do that way?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Why did they use LEFT JOIN and choose meta table as outer table in this query ? Isn't it ineffective to do that way?

```
SELECT meta.meta_value, COUNT( * ) AS meta_value_count
FROM $wpdb->commentmeta meta
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments comm ON meta.comment_id = comm.comment_ID
WHERE meta.meta_key = 'rating'
AND comm.comment_post_ID = %d
AND comm.comment_approved = '1'
AND meta.meta_value > 0
GROUP BY meta.meta_value
```

This is my alternative and explanation why it is better than the above:

```
SELECT meta.meta_value, COUNT( * ) AS meta_value_count
FROM $wpdb->comments comm /* comments table has better filters it should be outer table */
INNER JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta meta ON (comm.comment_ID = meta.comment_id AND meta.meta_key = 'rating' AND meta.meta_value > 0) /* there is no need to use left join because every commentmeta must has a not null corresponding comment row */
WHERE comm.comment_post_ID = %d /* a better filter to begin with */
AND comm.comment_approved = '1'
GROUP by meta.meta_value
```

Comment: What's the alternative? Besides, the ineffective (or, rather, inefficient) bit is the %d part.

Comment: To LEFT JOIN it is easier to add others LEFT JOINs if you need later.

Comment: But your query only returns rows in comm for which there are matching rows in meta.

Comment: Yes because  in the original query, only meta rows are needed. comm table is just for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the optimizer is smart enough to convert LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN if it knows that the conversion has no by-effect, and when it comes to INNER JOIN the order of left table and right table is reversible that is why it can pick the better outer table to optimize the query.

In fact, SQL is a weird language. The differences in commands are just appearance. Behind the scenes, it might be just the same.

http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-optimize-drupal-view-so-it-uses-inner-join-instead-left-join

> Because of this condition, MySQL considers LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN to
>   be equivalent and effectively treats this as an INNER JOIN. As a
>   result, field_data_field_user_updated table is first used to find 5
>   most recently updated uids and then corresponding fields are loaded
>   from the user table. This change reduced the time execution time from
>   about 1 second to about 0.13 seconds.